# Plotly Express: Writing image not working, processes for several minutes until Keyboard Interrupted

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

Attempting to save a figure to my computer, and no matter what I try, it just does not work! Here's what I'm exactly trying to save, and the code block just continues to "run" until I Keyboard Interrupt.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'notebook_connected'
fig = px.box(df, y = 'Total Series', x = 'Periods', color = 'Periods', color_discrete_sequence=['grey', 'purple', 'red'])
fig.update_layout(showlegend = False,
        paper_bgcolor="white",
        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        width = 800,
        title = {'text': 'Title',
                  'x': 0.5,
                  'xanchor': 'center',
                  'yanchor': 'top'},
        title_font = {'family': 'Verdana',
                      'color': 'rgb(0, 82, 136)'})
fig.update_xaxes({'title': "",
                      'color': 'rgb(0, 82, 136)'})
fig.update_yaxes({'title': "",
                      'color': 'rgb(0, 82, 136)'})
fig.update_traces(opacity=0.70)
fig.write_image('boxplot_generated/image.png')
```

When I attempt to use an extremely simple example, the same thing happens. What am I doing wrong? Where could the problem be coming from? I pip installed orca and kaleido and even imported them in the Jupyter notebook (VSCode). Here's the simplified example I tried.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 5, 6], 'B': [1, 2, 7, 8 ]})
fig = px.line(df, x = 'A')
fig.write_image('image.png')
```

I know it's kind of difficult to replicate because it's gotta be something outside of the code, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is plotly.io supposed to do?

Comment: the pio.renderers.default = 'notebook_connected' line is so I can view the plot in a VSCode Jupyter notebook

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of kaleido by any chance? If so, you need 0.1.0.post1, not the latest version, see the [plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/static-image-export-hangs-using-kaleido/61519/3) for its support.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pio.write_image(fig, 'boxplot_generated/image.png')
```

Comment: Nothing. Still watching a running cell.